# How to pass multiple objects as context to templates in class based generic view in django?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I need to pass two different objects to my template,I tried to pass but it showing only one.

I tried to pass it as dict but i got stuck, then i choose this method which also results in getting only the data from the first object.

In template tag i used

views.py

```
class ShowTable(ListView):
    model = TestUser

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)    
        context['vechile'] = Vechile.objects.all()
        return context
```

testuser_list.html

```
 {% for comment in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ comment.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ comment.address }}</td>
            <td>{{ comment.phone }}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'myapp:edit-table' comment.id %}">edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'myapp:delete-table' comment.id %}">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

 {% for comment in object_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ comment.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ comment.bike }}</td>
                <td>{{ comment.car }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

I need to display data from both the models(TestUser and Vechile), Now i'm getting data from TestUser model only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug this by adding `print(context)` to the view before `return context`, or by using the `django-debug-toolbar`. You will see that the context contains `object_list` and `vechile`.

Therefore, in the template, you can do:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {{ object }}
{% endfor %}

{% for v in vechile %}
    {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Still its not showing do i need to add model in url? I used like this 
   url(r'^show-data/$', views.ListView.as_view(model=TestUser), name='show-data'),

Comment: You are using `views.ListView.as_view()`, so `ShowTable` and its `get_context_data` method are not used. You should use `ShowTable.as_view()` in your URL pattern (make sure you import it first).